After writing data in batches using insertRecordsOfOneDevice, why did Apache IoTDB reported "could not create ServerSocket" error?
Currently, I stored 1000 parameters, 14.7 million time series data in Apache IoTDB. I set the data to be written into IoTDB once every 1000 time series, and this org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket error is prompted after writing 34,000 time series data in batches through session.insertRecordsOfOneDevice. When this error is reported, is it because the connection between IoTDB and session tool failed? Or what other reasons may cause this to happen?

It seems that the request data size of writing into Apache IoTDB exceeds the default limit of thrift settings. You can adjust your writing batch to be smaller, or you can increase the limit value. If you want to change the limit value, you can change the dn_thrift_max_frame_size parameter in iotdb-datanode.properties, and the IoTDB server needs to be restarted to activate this new setting.
